# Problema para ler uma variável da struct do tipo char

Tags: c, struct

estou treinando struct em c, porém eu não estou conseguindo ler a variável nome depois da primeira iteração, como na imagem abaixo.O que poderia ser o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Aluno
{
    char nome[10];
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float mediaAluno;

};

int main()
{
    struct Aluno fichaAlunos[4];
    int i  = 0;

    char aux[10];

    printf("--------Cadastro de aluno--------\n");

    while(i < 4)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
        fgets(fichaAlunos[i].nome, 10, stdin);


        printf("Digite a nota 1: ");
        scanf("%f", &fichaAlunos[i].nota1);
      

        printf("Digite a nota 2: ");
        scanf("%f", &fichaAlunos[i].nota2);
        printf("\n");

        fichaAlunos[i].mediaAluno = (fichaAlunos[i].nota1 + fichaAlunos[i].nota2)/2;

        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        printf("Aluno: %s , media: %.1f\n", fichaAlunos[i].nome, fichaAlunos[i].mediaAluno);

        i++;
    }
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor, evite colocar blocos de código (ou informações que poderiam estar escritas) como imagens. Para mais informações, você pode ler [este post sobre como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A função fgets() é utilizada normalmente para leitura de arquivo.
https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/fgets-function-in-c/

Utilize a outra função:
scanf("%s", fichaAlunos[i].nome);

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).